# Watir can't find element but it's present

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, watir, page-object-gem

I'm transitioning from the following environment:

```
chromedriver 2.27
google-chrome 58
selenium-webdriver 3.0.5
watir 6.0.2
page-object 2.0.0
```

to the this environment:

```
chromedriver 2.36
google-chrome 63
selenium-webdriver 3.9.0
watir 6.7.3
page-object 2.2.2
```

I already have my cucumber tests ready and working on the old environment and some of them are working properly in the new enviorment, but for some reason there is one test that refuses to find a certain element and gives me the following exception (even though the element is clearly present in the page and in the DOM):

```
timed out after 30 seconds, Element not present in 30 seconds (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
```

the element is defined as such:

```
table(:some_table, :css => 'table.table.table-condensed.table-striped.sortable tbody')
```

Did anybody encounter the same issue, I've been looking a lot and couldn't find a solution to this problem.

EXAMPLE:

Feature file:

```
Feature: HTML Tables

  Scenario:  Demo of reproducing the problem

    Given I am logged in to HTML Tables page
    Then within 10 I expect to see Alfreds Futterkiste in the table
```

Steps:

```
Given(/I am logged in to HTML Tables page$/) do 
  visit HtmlTables
end

Then(/^within (.+) I expect to see (.+) in the table$/) do |time_limit, element|
  on HtmlTables do |page|
    actual_element = page.search_for_element(element, time_limit)
    expect(actual_element).to match(element), "Expected element to match: #{element}; got: #{actual_element}"
  end
end
```

Page:

```
class HtmlTables
  include PageObject

  page_url "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"

  table(:html_table,                   :css    => 'tbody')

  def search_for_element(element, time_limit)
    Retriable.retriable on: [Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException],
                      tries: time_limit.to_i/10,
                      base_interval: 10 do
      html_table_element.each do |row|
        return row[0].text if row[0].text == element
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

It gives out the same exact problem - I think it has a problem locating using css and/or xpath.

Comment: Do you have the option to go to the latest Watir version, currently 6.10.3? I think 6.8.x made a number of fixes around locating elements.

Comment: @JustinKo I’ve upgraded to 6.9.0 and it has the same problem. Do you think 6.10.x will make the difference ?

Comment: I don't think it will solve the problem, but given you're upgrading versions, it might be the best to upgrade to the latest for everything. Can you try creating a page that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @JustinKo I added an example (in the question) and also upgraded to the latest versions and it didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Watir is being told to find a table element, however the `:css` locator is finding a tbody element. The current version of Watir validates that the element found has the matching tag name. While I thought Watir had always been doing this, it's possible that there were some edge cases addressed in the recent re-factoring of the Locator class.

Ideally you would be able to switch the `table` accessor to a `tbody` one. However, there isn't one implemented. Instead, you'll need to use the generic `element` one:

```
element(:html_table, :tbody, css: 'tbody')
```

Iterating the rows of the table will require explicitly calling `#trs`:

```
html_table_element.trs.each do |row|
  return row[0].text if row[0].text == element
end
```

Comment: That works, only that for some reason it doesn't give out the text in the cell but instead I get this:
#<Watir::Cell:0x000000033b5fd0>

Comment: That's the value returned by #search_for_element? I can see something like that getting returned if there are no matches in the table, though I got rows instead of cell elements.